# C# compile error in sublime text 3. it runs cmd

Tags: c#, compiler-errors

When I compile my c# progam it's a single Hello world! program. Sublime text instead of run program runs cmd. And in panel of sublime text says Microsoft (R) Visual C# Compiler version 4.7.3056.0

for C# 5
Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.

This compiler is provided as part of the Microsoft (R) .NET Framework, but only supports language versions up to C# 5, which is no longer the latest version. For compilers that support newer versions of the C# programming language, see http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=533240

test.cs(4,21): error CS0542: "Main": ����� 童��� �� ����� ᮢ������ � ⨯���, � ����� ��� �室��
test.cs(3,7): (���⮯�������� ᨬ���� �⭮�⥫쭮 �।��饩 �訡��)
[Finished in 0.2s]

Answer (score 0):

Consider using Visual Code for C# instead of Sublime which is more suitable for frontend development rather than backend.

https://code.visualstudio.com/

It is a lightweight version of Visual Studio. It has a good Intellisense feature and tools for C# and a lot of other popular languages like Java/Phyton/JavaScript/TypeScript, HTML/CSS etc.

Free for non-commercial usage